# Determining whether a UTC timestamp is within a time range in a timezone?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time, timezone, postgresql-9.4

Let's frame this problem as a scheduling application. Users specify a minimum time *in their timezone* ("8am" in "America/New_York") after which they're willing to take appointments. (we also have a similar constraint on the maximum time)

Given an incoming appointment request (say, for `2016-09-07 03:00:00` in UTC time), we need to determine which users can take the appointment.

**How can we determine whether a UTC timestamp is between two timezone-adjusted times?**

My approach has been to convert the incoming timestamp to the user's timezone, extract the time portion and compare it to the time constraints:

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE
   ('2016-09-07 03:00:00' AT TIME ZONE u.timezone)::time >= u.earliest_start_time AND
   ('2016-09-07 03:00:00' AT TIME ZONE u.timezone)::time <= u.latest_stop_time
```

(`earliest_start_time` and `latest_stop_time` are of type `time without time zone`; `timezone` is an Olson tz string)

There's all sorts of odd behavior as timezone offsets causes days to roll over and I'm just generally very confused and hazy about this.

Comment: You can't necessarily, because a local timestamp can be ambiguous. For example, suppose your user gives you a local range ending at 2016-11-06T01:30 New York time. Now, is 2016-11-05T21:45 before or after that? It's after the *first* occurrence of 1:30am in New York on November 6th, but it's before the *second* occurrence of 1:30am... Basically, you need to know whether the "1:30am" given by the user is the first or second occurrence... and cope with the other situation, where the user says 1:30am but that was skipped...

Comment: What is the type of `earliest_start_time` and `latest_stop_time`? Does it contain date information or is it just a time of day?

Comment: Ah. I think I understand. Given that I have a minimum and maximum constraint, I'd have to somehow encode in the query the assumption that I mean the range going through the night?

Comment: @redneb just time. Updated the question.

Comment: So are these appointment start times for specific dates, or on a (more or less, t.b.d) regular basis, like every weekday from 9 to 5 or Wednesdays between 4 and 6? If the latter, then you should not compare times only, but the full date; so create the UTC timestamps for this date and start/stop time (taking user timezone into account), and then compare based on that.

Comment: @CBroe it's the former; the incoming dates are all one-offs, not regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code below more readable, suppose that the placeholder `$1` holds a value of type `timestamp with time zone`. Then the following query will find all users that are available at that time:

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE
    $1 BETWEEN
      ($1::date || ' ' || u.earliest_start_time)::timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE u.timezone
    AND
      ($1::date || ' ' || u.latest_stop_time)::timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE u.timezone;
```

Explanation: we take `$1` which is a `timestamp with time zone` and we keep only the date part by type casting it into a `date`. Then we take `earliest_start_time` which is a time and combine it with the previous date and we get full time stamp which doesn't have time zone information (yet). Then we specify the time zone to convert that into a `timestamp with time zone`. We do the same for `latest_stop_time`. So now that we have found those 2 `timestamp with time zone` values, we can just compare them with `$1` which has the same type.

This will have problem with ambiguous timestamps though (i.e. in the transition from DST to standard time), but you cannot avoid that. If you only use it for typical businesses hours, it might be ok.